# how to route ONLY OUTLOOK to a VPN Tunnel, and not the whole trafic

Tags: vpn

I have a home office, and I use a VPN Tunnel to connect to my office.
For Work I use Outlook 2013 to read the email (And I must connect to the VPN Tunnel for this) and Firefox and Web-Radio for my private things I do, and I do not want my bos to know :))

I found http://old.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/ 
but it seems to not work with Win7, and its not with Buttons :)

Is there any Software (Something with Windows and Buttons ;-) ) that can be used to configure with app to use witch interface?

Again, I want JUST Outlook to use the Tunnel.

Any suggestions ?

```
Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : company.intern
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe11::c3fa:c8fe:e71c:cb2b%42
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.254.181
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe83::493d:6eb6:c4d9:aac3%10
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.107
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

Tunnel adapter isatap.company.intern:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : plastic.intern

Tunnel adapter isatap.{4C99B786-3BDD-4F27-A2CE-DDB4C3BA2B1C}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an IP access list.  Simply match all traffic going to the IP address of the Exchange server?...

Split tunneling is the setup where only traffic destined for the company's private network are tunneled.  All other traffic is sent out your local Internet pipe.  This is probably already how it is setup and would meet your requirements.

Simply ask them is they have split tunneling enabled or not.  If they do, you're all good already.